# Using Formula.js to get result from formula as string

Tags: javascript, formula

https://formulajs.info/

https://github.com/formulajs/formulajs

I am trying to utilize `formula.js` where user is passing a formula using input element.

The user is passing  string from input as:-

```
'SUM(1,2)'
```

However, formulajs is accepting in the below format as:-

```
formulajs.SUM(1, 2)
```

How to handle 'SUM(1,2)' using formula.js?

Answer (score 0):

Well, [their example](https://formulajs.info/functions/) just bites the bullet - and does it with `eval`. Here's their code:

```
$('#formula-box').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#out').val(eval($('#in').val()));
});
```

... with all the caveats of that approach. The idea is that global scope is already extended with all the functions supported by Formula.js, so `eval("ISOWEEKNUM('3/9/2012')")` will call a function `ISOWEEKNUM` passing `3/9/2012` as an argument.

The alternative is parsing the expression, separating the name of the function (an identifier followed by optional whitespace followed by `(` character) from the parameters (which can be valid JS expressions), then passing the extracted data name and parameters into your code.

If you decide to go this way, you can do it on your own for simple cases, but I strongly suggest reusing one the packages (such as [jsep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsep)) to get the expression parts evaluated.

Comment: Since eval have security concern, so using formulajs will not be safer?. So if we choose jsep or esprima to convert to syntax tree but then how to evaluate the valid js expression at the end.

Comment: Formula.js does have a small [parser part](https://github.com/formulajs/formulajs/blob/master/lib/utils/criteria-eval.js), but it's quite limited in its capabilities and is only used to handle expressions passed as string arguments (for `SUMIF` functions, for example).

Comment: So if we choose jsep or esprima to convert to syntax tree but then how to get the result out of valid js string at the end.